# How to use multiple bounds in java generics in this case

Tags: java, android, generics

I am trying to create a constructor for something like this.

```
public <T extends AppCompatActivity & DialogInterface.OnDismissListener> GooglePlayUtils(T activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

Android studio doesn't give any complains about this, but build fails on CompileDebugJava

However if remove the second bound, compilation works fine.
Am I doing it wrong or is there some other factor involved that I am missing?

**Edit**
After adding the type parameter to class itself rather than constructor solved the issue for me. But am still keeping the question open so someone can give the explanation why so?

**Edit 2**
Added the type parameter to class instead of constructor

```
public abstract class GooglePlayUtils<T extends AppCompatActivity & DialogInterface.OnDismissListener> {

private T activity;

public GooglePlayUtils(T activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

**Error**

> java.lang.AssertionError: 
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:133)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.check(Assert.java:86)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribBounds(Attr.java:561)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitMethodDef(Attr.java:723)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodDecl.accept(JCTree.java:669)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:431)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:418)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribStat(Attr.java:480)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClassBody(Attr.java:3250)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClass(Attr.java:3173)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClass(Attr.java:3109)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitClassDef(Attr.java:708)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCClassDecl.accept(JCTree.java:591)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:431)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:418)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribStat(Attr.java:480)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitNewClass(Attr.java:1790)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCNewClass.accept(JCTree.java:1372)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:431)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:418)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribExpr(Attr.java:449)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitAssign(Attr.java:1993)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCAssign.accept(JCTree.java:1466)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:431)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:418)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribExpr(Attr.java:460)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitExec(Attr.java:1294)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCExpressionStatement.accept(JCTree.java:1167)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:431)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:418)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribStat(Attr.java:480)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribStats(Attr.java:496)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitBlock(Attr.java:918)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBlock.accept(JCTree.java:781)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:431)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:418)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribStat(Attr.java:480)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitMethodDef(Attr.java:836)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodDecl.accept(JCTree.java:669)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:431)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:418)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribStat(Attr.java:480)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClassBody(Attr.java:3250)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClass(Attr.java:3173)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClass(Attr.java:3109)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attrib(Attr.java:3083)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.attribute(JavaCompiler.java:1184)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile2(JavaCompiler.java:870)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:829)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:439)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:132)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:45)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:33)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:101)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:50)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:36)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
>       at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:157)
>       at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:137)
>       at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:91)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1481.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:243)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:230)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:208)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:310)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
>       at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
>       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
>       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:90)
>       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:49)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>       at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:71)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: What's the inheritence look like for both classes?

Comment: Glad you found the answer, but you need to show the actual error so we can help identify the cause.

Comment: @Rogue AppCompatActivity is a class and OnDismissListener is an interface (Android classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Were you trying to create a generic class, or a concrete class whose constructor takes generic arguments?

If you were trying to create a generic class, that can be instantiated for objects that extend `AppCompatActivity & DialogInterface.OnDismissListener`, you need to make the class generic (as in your edit). In a generic class, the class type parameters don't need to be repeated in the constructor definition, they are assumed by the compiler implicitly.

If you were trying to create a class of some concrete or generic type whose constructor can accept objects that extend `AppCompatActivity & DialogInterface.OnDismissListener`, you need a way to explicitly cast that parameter to whatever type `this.activity` is defined as. The only way to assign your generic `activity` parameter to `this.activity` without casting is if they are the same type after type erasure.

While it is possible to create a constructor whose arguments are generic, you cannot assign a generic argument to one of a different type (after type erasure) without casting.

Comment: A helpful tip for anyone reading this, since the question involves multiple bounds: when using extends with `&`, only a single class type parameter bound is supported, and it must be listed first. So, for example, `extends DialogInterface.OnDismissListener & AppCompatActivity` is not allowed, although `extends AppCompatActivity & DialogInterface.OnDismissListener` is ok. ["A list of bounds consists of one class and/or several interfaces."](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#Topic2)